# Classifier of the GEE

Tags: classifyjs

I'm new on the GEE and I'm trying to make landcover and I'm getting error

> classified image: Layer error: Classifier.cart: This classifier has been removed.  For more information see: http://goo.gle/deprecated-classifiers

how to fix it?

[link of the project](https://code.earthengine.google.com/66d70fdc46a7eb90dd4b29eb77ba2b24)

Answer (score 0):

Classifier.cart has been update to  Classifier.smileCart